# Iam want to get sum of degree for each row with json

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

Hello I have a problem with PHP laravel with JSON I am saving in filled

- JSON data name is element_degree
- The key is the element and the value is the degree

Problem I want show user data and get sum of degree for each user how can I do this ?

This is my data:

| Id | User | Month | Element_degree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2 | 2 | "{"13":"122","14":"130"}" |
| 14 | 3 | 2 | "{"13":"100","14":"120"}" |
| 15 | 4 | 2 | "{"13":"140","14":"100"}" |

And this is my code in controller:

```
$data=empdata::all()
```

How can I get a sum of degrees for each row from field element_degree for each user ?

Comment: I just would like to ask you: is the edit fine ? Or you prefer another way to show your data ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will add element_degree_total field in your emp data for each data

```
$employees = empdata::all();
    foreach($employees as $employee){
        $data = json_decode($employee->element_degree);
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($data as $d) {
             $total += $d;
        }
        $employee->element_degree_total = $total;
    }
```